# RESTful API desgin: retrieve number of items in category

Tags: rest, api

I want to create a REST API with items in categories and list all categories alongside its number of items.

**Schemas:**

```
Category {id, name}
Item {id, name, categoryId}
```

**Endpoints:**

```
GET    /categories/list
GET    /categories/<id>
PUT    /categories/<id>

GET    /items/list[?category=<categoryId>]
GET    /items/<id>
```

To update a category I take what I get from `GET /categories/<id>`, modify the JSON object and `PUT` it back.

So far so good.

My question is if there are one ore more best practices to retrieve the item count?
I can think of a few ways to do this:

1. Fire a `GET /items/list?category=<categoryId>` for each category, counting the resulting items.
   *Taking the count from a `X-total-count` or `content range` header or a `total_count` field returned from the endpoint will avoid having to actually load all items.*
2. Add an `item_count` field to the resulting category JSON objects.
   *How should this read only field be handled for `PUT`s? Make the backend ignore it? Manually unset it?*
3. Create a dedicated endpoint `/categories/item_counts` that returns a list of categories with each number of items.

I like option number 2 (e.g. [the wordpress API does it this way](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/categories/)) because it does not need extra requests. But I really dislike the idea of having a different object structure for the `GET` and `PUT` requests.

Answer (score 2):

REST is really about representation of objects. `Category` doesn't have a count as it's a single object. `Item` doesn't have a count either for the same reason. Count is more like RPC where you tell the service to compute something.

```
GET /items/list[?category=<categoryId>]
```

is like RPC, passing the `category` parameter to the `list` method. Staying in that idiom, you could "chain" the methods to get the total count of items in the specified category:

```
GET /items/list/count[?category=<categoryId>]
```

although I'd use path parameters instead:

```
GET /items/list/<category_id>/count
```

but `list` is implied so you could remove it:

```
GET /items/<category_id>/count
```

It's straying a bit from "pure" REST but it keeps your actual REST objects clean, as you say, keeping `total_count` our of your `Category` objects.

I'm assuming you sometimes need the count but not all the `Item`s otherwise you wouldn't need to ask the API for the count, you'd just count them yourself in the client. That suggests another option:

```
GET /categories/<id>/count
{
  "total_count": 10
}
```

which fits better with the use case of finding out how many `Item`s are in a `Category`.